# How to proxy web service for a large file?

Tags: playframework-2.0

My app is using **Java Play 2.0.4** and I need to implement a controller that calls a web service (hosted on another server on the same host) which returns a video, very often of large size. I'm not sure if it is relevant, but the video is in m4v/mp4 format.

Which is the correct way to do this?
I suspect using `AsyncResult` would be correct, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Currently, I'm calling the web service and getting a Promise the following way:

```
Promise<Response> promise = WS.url(videoUrl).get();
```

After that I'm simply getting the response as bytes, manually setting the headers and returning it to the view:

```
Response response = promise.value().get();
byte[] video = response.ahcResponse().getResponseBodyAsBytes();
response().setContentType(format.equals("m4v") ? "video/x-m4v" : "application/x-shockwave-flash");
response().setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
response().setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-" + String.valueOf(video.length-1) + "/" + String.valueOf(video.length));
return ok(video);
```

This works sometimes, however the behaviour is very erratic. Some (shorter) videos load just fine. Larger videos fail since the request gets cancelled. I also noted the request to the action which call the web service is made several times. Always returning the full length of the video (or what it could load before the request got canceled).

I might also add I'm calling the action from the `src` attribute of a html5 `video` tag, which maps to a route for that action.

I also noted most videos in html5 are served in a 206 Partial Content response status (for example, http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4) which I think is needed to stream the video.

Any help would be very much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Thanks in advance!

Gonzalo

Comment: for scala implementation see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736320/play2-framework-proxy-streaming-content-to-client-keeps-connection-open-after-st/19119665#19119665

Answer (score 2):

I had quite similar task some time ago: [How to send Windows Azure Storage blob to browser with changed header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14787259/1066240) and I finished with ... `java.net.URL`, as I had problems with proper handling timeouts, not founds, etc.

For now it's working well, but I have no huge files, just about 30 - 200 mb.

Although I'm not sure if this approach will satisfy you, you can just check, and also send some response... maybe I'll will correct my point of view as well :)

```
public static Result movie(String path) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        response().setHeader(CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING, "binary");
        return ok(url.openStream()).as("video/mp4");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        warn("Path " + path + " is not working...");
        return badRequest("Movie server didn't answer");
    }
}
```

(*sorry for not correcting the snippet for your situation, just copy-paste... I think you will get the idea with no problems*)

Comment: Thanks @biesior. I tried that but I still get the request cancelled. I think it might be a browser (maybe video format/encoding?) issue, since it works just fine on Safari, but not on Chrome/Firefox...